# What is wrong with my syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a global dictionary for my module, but it keep telling me that my syntax is wrong. I did I wrong?

```
_dummy_date = dict{
    '0'=datetime(year=1990, month=1, day=1, hour=0,minutes=0,second=0),
    '1'=datetime(year=1990, month=1, day=2, hour=0,minutes=0,second=0),
    '2'=datetime(year=1990, month=1, day=3, hour=0,minutes=0,second=0),
    '3'=datetime(year=1990, month=1, day=4, hour=0,minutes=0,second=0),
    '4'=datetime(year=1990, month=1, day=5, hour=0,minutes=0,second=0),
    '5'=datetime(year=1990, month=1, day=6, hour=0,minutes=0,second=0),
    '6'=datetime(year=1990, month=1, day=7, hour=0,minutes=0,second=0)
}
```

Here is the error

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/modules/module.py", line 367, in load_openerp_module
    __import__('odoo.addons.' + module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/modules/module.py", line 81, in load_module
    execfile(modfile, new_mod.__dict__)
  File "/mnt/extra-addons/jy_attendance_base/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import models
  File "/mnt/extra-addons/jy_attendance_base/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import models
File "/mnt/extra-addons/jy_attendance_base/models/models.py", line 8
    _dummy_date = dict{
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The syntax is `bla = dict(a=0)` or `bla = {'a':0}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dict() is a method, so you must call it explicitly:

```
dict()
```

Also, a dict constructed this way is not separated with an equal(=) sign, but a colon, like so:

```
_dummy_date = dict({
    '0':datetime(year=1990, month=1, day=1, hour=0,minutes=0,second=0),
    '1':datetime(year=1990, month=1, day=2, hour=0,minutes=0,second=0),
    '2':datetime(year=1990, month=1, day=3, hour=0,minutes=0,second=0),
    '3':datetime(year=1990, month=1, day=4, hour=0,minutes=0,second=0),
    '4':datetime(year=1990, month=1, day=5, hour=0,minutes=0,second=0),
    '5':datetime(year=1990, month=1, day=6, hour=0,minutes=0,second=0),
    '6':datetime(year=1990, month=1, day=7, hour=0,minutes=0,second=0)
})
```

But, since you're creating your dictionary explicitly, you can remove the `dict()` call at all, and simply write:

```
_dummy_date = {
    '0':datetime(year=1990, month=1, day=1, hour=0,minutes=0,second=0),
    '1':datetime(year=1990, month=1, day=2, hour=0,minutes=0,second=0),
    '2':datetime(year=1990, month=1, day=3, hour=0,minutes=0,second=0),
    '3':datetime(year=1990, month=1, day=4, hour=0,minutes=0,second=0),
    '4':datetime(year=1990, month=1, day=5, hour=0,minutes=0,second=0),
    '5':datetime(year=1990, month=1, day=6, hour=0,minutes=0,second=0),
    '6':datetime(year=1990, month=1, day=7, hour=0,minutes=0,second=0)
}
```

And this will simply create the dict as you like

Comment: Thank you, I fixed. But I'm not really sure, but I have seen someone asking what is a difference by between `blah=dict{a='b'}` and `blah={a:'b'}`

Comment: ```blah=dict{a='b'}``` is not a proper syntax, you cannot write that way.
You may mean ```blah=dict(a='b')``` with regular parentheses.
And the difference between ```blah=dict(a='b')``` and ```blah={a:'b'}``` is that the first calls the constructor ```dict()``` explicitly and the second does not, which means it will take less time to compute. As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664118/whats-the-difference-between-dict-and)