# Different memory size of dict() and {} in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

There is this problem I cannot get my head around to solve. So in order to create a dictionary, we have two ways: (1) a function call `dict()` and (2) literal syntax `{}`.

When I check the memory size of creation of two empty dictionaries, `sys.getsizeof()` return different memory size:

```
import sys

my_dict1 = {}
sys.getsizeof(my_dict1)
# 64
```

For syntax `{}`, by running this example you can see that the basic occupation of a Python dictionary is 64 bytes (8 buckets, each is 8 bytes, so 8 x 8 = 64). That makes sense to me. Since the `{}` syntax is handled in byte-code it can use this optimization mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/681358/1757224).

and

```
import sys

my_dict2 = dict()
sys.getsizeof(my_dict2)
# 232
```

But for `dict()`, it is 232 bytes. I think this huge difference is due to the different implementations. `dict()` is handled like a regular class constructor and Python uses the generic memory allocator, which does not follow an easily predictable pattern like the free list (again, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/681358/1757224) is great).

However, what I do not understand starts here, even if I start my empty dictionary using `{}` and begin to add elements to this empty dictionary, memory size jumps to 232 from 64 in the first iteration.

```
import sys

my_dict = {}
for i in range(20):
    my_dict[i] = 100
    print(f"elements = {i+1} size = {sys.getsizeof(my_dict)}")
    
# elements = 1 size = 232
# elements = 2 size = 232
# elements = 3 size = 232
# elements = 4 size = 232
# elements = 5 size = 232
# elements = 6 size = 360
# elements = 7 size = 360
# elements = 8 size = 360
# elements = 9 size = 360
# elements = 10 size = 360
# elements = 11 size = 640
# elements = 12 size = 640
# elements = 13 size = 640
# elements = 14 size = 640
# elements = 15 size = 640
# elements = 16 size = 640
# elements = 17 size = 640
# elements = 18 size = 640
# elements = 19 size = 640
# elements = 20 size = 640
```

In order to make Python hash table fast and reduce collisions, the interpreter keeps resizing the dictionary when it becomes full for two-third. That I know.

What I do not understand, why in the VERY FIRST insertion, the memory size goes from 64 to 232, even though empty dictionary started by `{}` is 64 bytes. Because when I create an empty dictionary using `{}`, I use special opcodes for the containers, instead of performing function calls.

EDIT: Python version I am using is 3.8.12.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in my Python 3.10.6 REPL. (Sorry for the formatting; this is a comment so I can't do much better.) `>>> sys.getsizeof({})`: 64; `>>> sys.getsizeof(dict())`: 64

Comment: Can't reproduce this with two .py files either.

Comment: I _can_ reproduce for 3.8.10 (same numbers)

Comment: I never noticed that but if this is what's really happening then I guess that when you do `my_dict = {}`  it isn't initialize as an instance of the class but as soon as you add something then it becomes an object.

Comment: 3.9.13 also shows this behavior, actually. So there we go, it's an implementation detail that has changed between 3.9 and 3.10...

Comment: @AKX for me (python 3.8.3) `>>> sys.getsizeof({})`: 40; `>>> sys.getsizeof(dict())`: 128

Comment: Somebody call Raymond Hettinger for explanation. That's really an implementation detail.

Comment: @Anto I'll go ahead and guess you're on 32-bit Python.

Comment: @AKX True ! haha I didn't even know I'll go and change that right now

Comment: By the way, the "8 x 8" theory is probably wrong – I'd guess the size comes from [the size of the struct](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Include/cpython/dictobject.h#L11-L29).

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the answer is *because implementation details* and *how much does it really matter to userland code…?* How deep do you want to dig here…?

Comment: @deceze Yeah, this really shouldn't matter, especially since it has changed in the current CPython version, and OP's theories of how Python dictionaries work may not reflect reality anyway. Anyway, someone _could_ delve into CPython source to figure this out if they wanted to.

Comment: @AKX Yes, it only matters to actual code 1) in specific Python versions 2) when you have massive numbers of empty dicts. Case 2 is probably extremely rare, and even if you have that case and need to optimise, it'll only help in case 1, so… meh… At best some interesting tidbit about the Python internals may fall out of this, but not much more.

Comment: One more thing: the linked answers are from 2009, 13 years ago. The state of Python art in 2009 was Python 2.6.

Comment: I forgot to write down. I am using Python 3.8.12.

Comment: @ARAT Also: I don't see what the problem (that you can't get your head around), or in fact, question in your post is. Is the question "can someone explain why this happens"? If so, the answer is "because the CPython implementation does these things". If the follow-up question is "why does it do these things", then the answer is likely to be "because the implementers of CPython are smarter than you and me", and the real reasons are found in the CPython source.

Comment: @AKX I just want to understand. I know I can comfort myself with "CPython implementation does these things".  I want to hear what's happening behind because I cannot figure out. Alright?

Comment: @ARAT If you want to understand and learn what's happening behind the scenes, you would need to get your hands dirty by running e.g. the `gdb` debugger on the affected Python interpreter to see how the internals of your dictionary object change (if you can't figure it out from the interpreter source itself).

Comment: As a stab into the dark, I'd guess the parser might allocate some minimal struct at parse time when it encounters `{}` in the source, whereas `dict()` is a runtime call which initialises the object differently, going through a more complete initialisation phase. Something like that. *Maybe* it's a purposeful optimisation, maybe it just happens to fall out of the implementation details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Python 3.8.12, the version you're on, `dict()` allocates a new "keys object" (the part of the dict that stores the hash table, the keys, and in non-"split" dicts, the values), while `{}` uses a common "keys object" shared by many empty dicts. The shared keys object isn't counted towards the size of the `{}` dict.

Note that as soon as you add entries to the `{}` dict, it will need to allocate a non-shared keys object for its own use, so using `{}` won't actually save any memory in most cases.

You can see the code for `dict()` by looking at [`dict_new`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.12/Objects/dictobject.c#L3277) and [`dict_init`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.12/Objects/dictobject.c#L3304), the C functions corresponding to `dict.__new__` and `dict.__init__`.

You can see the code for `{}` in the bytecode evaluation loop, under the [`BUILD_MAP` opcode](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.12/Python/ceval.c#L2784), and follow that down to [`_PyDict_NewPresized`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.12/Objects/dictobject.c#L1313).

You can see the code that `sys.getsizeof` delegates to for a dict in [`dict_sizeof`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.12/Objects/dictobject.c#L3166), the C implementation of `dict.__sizeof__`. The code that ignores the size of the shared keys object for `{}` is `if (mp->ma_keys->dk_refcnt == 1)`, in `_PyDict_SizeOf`.

Comment: Okay, now I see why `{}` and `dict()` giving different memory size. I am sorry but I still cannot see why initializing an empty object with `{}` and adding elements in a loop, when I insert the first element, it jumps from 64 to 232. Should not it still be 64 bytes until 5th element added?

Comment: For reference, `d = {}` calls `BUILD_MAP` with `oparg = 0`.

Comment: @ARAT: The dict can't share a keys object with other empty dicts if it's not empty any more.

Comment: (Well, technically, there are cases where empty and non-empty dicts can share keys objects, but those would be a few very restricted cases with instance `__dict__`s. The empty keys object used for `{}` can't be shared by nonempty dicts.)